# fake python modules via symlinks: on windows?

Tags: python, symlink, python-module

I have several compiled python modules; they are put into a single `.so` (to avoid runtime linking, there are cross-module symbol dependencies), but a number of symlinks points to this `.so`:

```
foo.so -> liball.so
bar.so -> liball.so
liball.so
```

This way, I can do `import foo` (Python will call `initfoo()` defined in `liball.so`) or `import bar` (calls `initbar()`).

I am wondering if this approach will work on Windows?

Comment: A bit unclear: how have you compiled python modules to shared objects?

Comment: @BasicWold: Something like `g++ -shared -o liball.so foo.cpp bar.cpp -lboost_python` (and bunch of other compiler options)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not, but you could achieve your goal with

```
import sys
import liball
sys.modules['foo'] = liball
sys.modules['bar'] = liball
```

if you need to import them at several places, or with

```
import liball as foo, libalb as bar, liball
```

if you need that only at one place.

It might be, however, that the distinction between `initfoo()` and `initbar()` cannot be held and that both must be done so that the module effectively contains everything to be contained in both modules.

If `foo` partially contains the same symbols as `bar`, but with a different meaning, this approach won't work. But then you can just copy the file. This will occupy more disk space than needed, but that doesn't hurt so much, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good idea. I hope direct manipulation of `sys.modules` is not considered a bad practice which might break in the future ;-)